# Where I bind to XML when extends from ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, xml

when I extends from Activity, I modify the fragment_main and find controls like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    MyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
}
```

but when I do this when extends from from ActionBarActivity gives me an error, so to do it work I have to comment:

```
/*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}*/
```

and set activity_main to fragment_main

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

but I don't believe this be correct...

Comment: In which layout file is your R.id.button1 Button?

Comment: In fragment_main I use Blank activity from eclipse

Comment: Why do you want your Activity to extend ActionBarActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not get the button view on your activity, however it sides in a fragment. You can get it on your fragment such as `PlaceholderFragment` like you do on your activity. If needed, you should know something about how to interactive between `Activity` and `Fragment`. the link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html may help you.